# Why the AWS ElasticSearch endpoint is unchanged after re-deploy?

Tags: elasticsearch, aws-elasticsearch

I deleted the ES stack on AWS and recreate it, and I use the standard ES endpoint. But I found the endpoint doesn't change after I created the stack again.

This is the standard endpoint pattern: `https://search-mydomain-1a2a3a4a5a6a7a8a9a0a9a8a7a.us-east-1.es.amazonaws.com`

The random string `1a2a3a4a5a6a7a8a9a0a9a8a7a` doesn't change.

How does it generate?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Hi, what do you mean by 'recreate it'? Did you delete the ElasticSearch domain completely?

Comment: Hi, thank you for the response. I delete the stack actually, so there should be no domain anymore. But when `recreate`, I use the same domain name.